# Iterate over the linked list and print each value onto the screen C

Tags: c, linked-list

My input file is

```
1

2

3

4

5
```

And my output should look like

```
1 -> NULL

2 -> 1 -> NULL

3 -> 2 -> 1 -> NULL

4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> NULL

5 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> NULL
```

This is my function

```
void printList(Node* first)
{
    Node *temp;
    temp=first;

    printf("elements in linked list are\n");
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d -> NULL\n",temp->value);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

And this is the full program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int value;
    struct node* next;
}Node;

Node* createNode(int data);
Node* insertFront(Node* first, Node* newNode);
void printList(Node* first); 
void deleteList(Node* first);

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    int numItems, ch;
    FILE *fp;

    numItems = 0;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if(fp == NULL)
{
    fclose(fp);
    return -1;
}

    while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch = '\n') numItems++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    Node *first = NULL;
    Node *newNode;
    Node *Next;

    int i;

    for(i = 1; i <= numItems; i++)
    {
        newNode = createNode(i);
        first = insertFront(first, newNode);
    }

    printList(first);
    deleteList(first);

    return 1;
}

Node* createNode(int data)
{
    Node *newNode;

    newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    newNode -> value = data;

    newNode -> next = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

Node* insertFront(Node* first, Node* newNode)
{
    if (newNode == NULL) {
        /* handle oom */
    }

    newNode->next=NULL;

    if (first == NULL) {
        first = newNode;
    }

    else {
        Node *temp=first;

        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->next=newNode;

        first = newNode;
    }

    return first;
}

void printList(Node* first)
{
    Node *temp;
    temp=first;

    printf("elements in linked list are\n");
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d -> NULL\n",temp->value);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

void deleteList(Node* first)
{
    Node  *temp;
    temp=first;
    first=first->next;
    temp->next=NULL;
    free(temp);
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this, I'm riding the linked list struggle bus over here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what error are you getting?

Comment: Since you're going through the trouble of reading that file (which is never checked for open-success), perhaps storing its contents in your list would be apropos.

Comment: Im not having errors persay its just that I'm having trouble setting up my printed output to display properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors in there. Since this is a learning assignment, I would describe errors rather than correcting your code:

- You are printing `-> NULL` for each element; you should print it only when the loop has finished. In other words, the individual lines should use `"%d -> "` format, and then after the loop you should print `"NULL\n"`.
- Your `deleteList` is incorrect: you need a loop there, similar to what you have in  `printList`
- Your way of creating a list looks suspicious: rather than reading a file, you count lines, and then create a list of `0`, `1`, `2`, ... based on the line count. You should read the data from the file into your list; you can do it in the same loop that does counting, because linked lists do not need to know their length upfront.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the print to look something like the example you showed you should change `void printList(Node* first)` to something like this:

```
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    if( temp->next )
        printf("%d ->",temp->value);
    else
        printf("%d -> NULL\n",temp->value);
    temp=temp->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate the stack properly and ensure proper deletion when needed, you need to fix the problems mentioned in `dasblinkenlight`'s answer. Once that is done, your specific issue, how to print the output as desired:

```
1->NULL
2->1->NULL
```

and so on, is best addressed with a recursive call:

```
void printList (Node* stack) {

    Node* pCur = stack;  // you could just use stack, you don't have to have pCur

    if (pCur) {          
        printList (pCur->next);              
        while (pCur->next) {
            printf ("%d->", pCur->value)
            pCur = pCur->next;
        }
        printf ("%d->NULL\n", pCur->value);
    }
    return;
}
```